# How do I fabricate a sphere?

Tags: steel, structures

I'm want to make a 2 meters wide sphere that should be circular enough as a giant hamster ball! I could make it of some sort of strong plastic or steel. It should have a hatch on top that can be opened or closed so that anyone can enter.

EDIT: what I'm asking for is the topology of the sphere and how can I build it in a way that makes it completely rounded when assembled. I'm asking about the parts and assembling it

Comment: Hi None, welcome to Engineering SE. This looks like a set of specifications rather than a specific technical question. Please be more specific about what's preventing you from fabricating a sphere. What sort of tools and facilities do you have access to? What's your budget? What will the sphere be used for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a hamster ball I would say that a good approach would be to construct it from a series of rings in steel tube, rather like the lines of latitude and longitude on a globe with the gaps filled in with mesh. IIRC correctly a prop like this was used on  the *Gladiator* gameshow.

This is a fairly tricky fabrication to pull off as there are a lot of tube joints to be made and you will almost certainly need to construct a reasonably sophisticated jig to keep everything concentric and you need to consider carefully how you will handle the 'poles' where you will have a lot of tubes meeting at one point.

Large diameter circles of steel tube can be made using a [roll bender](http://www.baileighindustrial.co.uk/metalworking/roll-benders)  without too much difficulty although making a dozen of so with adequately consistent radius for this sort of application is not trivial.

Obviously any deviations from spherical will make it more difficult to handle as it will tend to pull in one direction or just move erratically. It also goes without saying that there are some fairly significant safety considerations which would need to be addressed.

The other alternative would be to mould it in some sort of composite material like fibreglass. Here the challenge is to produce a 2 m diameter spherical mould. The most sensible approach would be to make two hemispheres and bond them together. You may be able to find something off the shelf which would serve as a mould but I can't imagine what off hand. Failing that you would probably need to construct a plywood hemispherical framework,  skin it with plaster and then [turn](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gDYFqSQIUAM/T1IbFFU1ESI/AAAAAAAAAWo/9LhJKNl6LQc/s1600/13.jpg) it to an accurate hemisphere using a former mounted on a spindle.

A fibreglass structure of this size would also need to be reinforced with internal ribs or foam between two layers of laminate to be adequately stiff without being too heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [regular polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) for some ideas.

For example, it might be reasonable to construct a vacuum-forming mold for plexiglass sheets that creates a 5-sided section of a spherical surface. 12 of these could be assembled into a sphere, with one of them removable to create the hatch.

Comment: Good idea, especially if you can use simple CAD to accurately work out  the required dimensions for each element.